# Как составить регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Условия регулярного выражения:

1. Только латинские буквы в нижнем регистре.
2. Если буква в верхнем регистре - переводить её в нижний.
3. Допускается только дефис из знаков.
4. Цифры не допускаются.
5. Если встречается русская буква, то транслитом переводить её.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение, это ж просто фильтр. Фильтр не может изменять, поэтому как решение предлагаю написать функцию.

1. Литерал для только латинских букв в линжнем регистре - [a-z].
2. В PHP есть очень хорошая функция strtolower(), которая переводит буквы верхнего регистра в нижний.
3. Тут вот не помню, но вроде литерал [.-] такой или [.-/] что-то такое. Тут могу порекомендовать почитать мануалы к стандартным литералам регулярных выражений.
4. Это делает литерал из пункта 1.
5. В CMS DLE есть хорошая функция для этого дела вот она:

-

```
function totranslit($var, $lower = true, $punkt = true)
{
    global $langtranslit;

    if (is_array($var))
        return "";

    if (!is_array($langtranslit) OR !count($langtranslit)) {
        $langtranslit = array(
            'а' => 'a',
            'б' => 'b',
            'в' => 'v',
            'г' => 'g',
            'д' => 'd',
            'е' => 'e',
            'ё' => 'e',
            'ж' => 'zh',
            'з' => 'z',
            'и' => 'i',
            'й' => 'y',
            'к' => 'k',
            'л' => 'l',
            'м' => 'm',
            'н' => 'n',
            'о' => 'o',
            'п' => 'p',
            'р' => 'r',
            'с' => 's',
            'т' => 't',
            'у' => 'u',
            'ф' => 'f',
            'х' => 'h',
            'ц' => 'c',
            'ч' => 'ch',
            'ш' => 'sh',
            'щ' => 'sch',
            'ь' => '',
            'ы' => 'y',
            'ъ' => '',
            'э' => 'e',
            'ю' => 'yu',
            'я' => 'ya',
            "ї" => "yi",
            "є" => "ye",

            'А' => 'A',
            'Б' => 'B',
            'В' => 'V',
            'Г' => 'G',
            'Д' => 'D',
            'Е' => 'E',
            'Ё' => 'E',
            'Ж' => 'Zh',
            'З' => 'Z',
            'И' => 'I',
            'Й' => 'Y',
            'К' => 'K',
            'Л' => 'L',
            'М' => 'M',
            'Н' => 'N',
            'О' => 'O',
            'П' => 'P',
            'Р' => 'R',
            'С' => 'S',
            'Т' => 'T',
            'У' => 'U',
            'Ф' => 'F',
            'Х' => 'H',
            'Ц' => 'C',
            'Ч' => 'Ch',
            'Ш' => 'Sh',
            'Щ' => 'Sch',
            'Ь' => '',
            'Ы' => 'Y',
            'Ъ' => '',
            'Э' => 'E',
            'Ю' => 'Yu',
            'Я' => 'Ya',
            "Ї" => "yi",
            "Є" => "ye"
        );

    }

    $var = trim(strip_tags($var));
    $var = preg_replace("/\s+/ms", "-", $var);

    $var = strtr($var, $langtranslit);

    if ($punkt)
        $var = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-.]+/mi", "", $var);
    else
        $var = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-]+/mi", "", $var);

    $var = preg_replace('#[\-]+#i', '-', $var);

    if ($lower)
        $var = strtolower($var);

    $var = str_ireplace(".php", "", $var);
    $var = str_ireplace(".php", ".ppp", $var);

    if (strlen($var) > 200) {
        $var = substr($var, 0, 200);

        if (($temp_max = strrpos($var, '-')))
            $var = substr($var, 0, $temp_max);

    }

    return $var;
}
```

Но я вам рекомендую написать функцию, которая бы проверяла строку сначала на наличие чисел([0-9]), потом на наличие русскоязычного текста (вроде бы так: [А-Я][а-я]), ну и если кирилические символы есть, то переводила бы их на латиницу, а в конце просто отфильтровала только латинские символы.